# JSON parse objects with same string name

Tags: json, string, arrays

Fast question, here is my Json:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "4cd8fe75d",
            "name": "foo"
        },
        {
            "id": "5076c7e30",
            "name": "bar"
        },
        ......
        {
            "id": "6236c7e30",
            "name": "foobar"
        }
    ]
}
```

I know I can access the first `"name"` foo like that: `items[0].name`
But what about the other (and many others following on the string?

Generally: with .each() I can access every value on an array but what about every object in a sequence (not sure if I express my point correctly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`items[i].name` should get the name property of the i'th object in the array.

```
for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
    console.log(items[i].name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok it was more obvious than I thought:

```
$.each(items, function(i,item){
      alert(items[i].name);
      });
```

Comment: But this is what i posted too

Comment: @Asad never ignored you :) I was just stuck